# Code has stopped working - Scraping Data with Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am currently working on a scraping code with Snscrape and Pandas libraries. It has been working for the past month but now it has stopped. I use Windows 10 and notepad ++.

The code is as follows:

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd

tweets1 = []

for x, tweet in enumerate (sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('query: hate speech since: 2006-01-01 until:2015-01-01', 'geolocation: Wooler, 28km').get_items()):
    list1 = pd.DataFrame(tweets1, columns=['Datetime', 'Tweet Id', 'Text', 'Username'])

print(list1)

tweets.df1.to_csv("C:\SNS Scrape\Barbara code\\TweetData001.csv")
```

The output is:

```
[]
```

That is it...I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any advice would be amazing.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Looks like the scraper is not finding anything

Comment: Yeah, it states:

Comment: NameError: name 'list1' is not defined. I am pretty sure it is correct though, unless i am missing something

Comment: You are overwriting that variable for each tweet btw, so in this case, there are no matching tweets, so the variable isn't being created. I'd suggest look at your query since it's not finding any tweets.

Comment: I am breaking my code by parts: First the snscrape stuff but that is also not working: there is no output, but no error is occurring. import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame
tweets1 = []

for x, tweet in enumerate (sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('query: hate speech since:2006-01-01, until:2019-01-01, geolocation: Lancaster, 92km').get_items()):
    print (tweets1)

Comment: No error needs to occur for it to return nothing. You should simplify the query until you get something that works, then build it up again.